# Is it possible to force the browser to ignore "weak ephemeral Diffie-Hellman public key"?

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, opera

Is it possible to force the browser to ignore the *"Server has a weak ephemeral Diffie-Hellman public key"* error? I've tried it on Opera, Chrome and Firefox. But there is nothing too visible that allows me to ignore this.

Comment: -1: Not a great idea as this would leave your browser to vulnerable to Logjam. See: http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/89689/what-is-logjam-and-how-do-i-prevent-it

Comment: @DragonLord That doesn't make sense. The user knows (or should know) exactly what he's doing. And also, in the rules given by the help center, that's is not a feasible reason for closing.

Comment: I hope the answer is [here](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/93117/firefoxsecure-connection-failederror-codessl-error-weak-server-ephemeral-dh-k)

Answer (score 5):

Yes, just tell the browser you want to use an insecure connection by using the `http` protocol instead of `https`.

The browser is warning you because you requested a secure connection (via `https`), and the public key provided by the server is *not secure*.

TLS errors are not something users should casually ignore. If you don't care about security, then just tell the browser to use the insecure protocol; don't tell the browser to use the secure protocol and then ignore any errors with the security. That defeats the purpose.

Comment: It's not the case that I don't care about security. It's more a matter of urgency: I need to access one site to obtain the barcodes of my water bills and then pay them via internet banking. I called them and asked for them to send me the barcodes via e-mail, they agreed but never sent me. I'm really trying to avoid waiting for them.

Answer (score 4):

Answer was given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31525522/246892) :

> Type in your browser (I tried in Iceweasel)
>
> ```
>     about:config
> ```
>
> Search for
>
> ```
>     security.ssl3.dhe_rsa_aes_128_sha 
>
>     security.ssl3.dhe_rsa_aes_256_sha 
>
>     security.ssl3.dhe_rsa
> ```
>
> Set them both to `false` (just double click to set them to `false` or
>   `true`).

That works for everything but Chrome it appears. In Chrome you [must](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32441883/246892) type:

> `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --cipher-suite-blacklist=0x0088,0x0087,0x0039,0x0038,0x0044,0x0045,0x0066,0x0032,0x0033,0x0016,0x0013"`

Answer (score 0):

For Internet Explorer 11:
add this registry key:

Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\KeyExchangeAlgorithms\Diffie-Hellman]
"ClientMinKeyBitLength"=dword:00000200